# How to use 5v and 12v addressable led strip together

Tags: power, adafruit, voltage, neopixel, convert

Hi guys I’m new to this forum and also not much experience about led lights question already asked but didn’t get any detailed answer I want to know can I provide working data signal to 2 different 5v and 12v addressable led strips or what should I do to work them in same patterns at same time it will be really big help please and thanks in advance I’m sure I’m at right forum because usually I get all my answers by you guys without even asking

Comment: Actually this is not a forum, but a Q&A site. About what LED strips are we speaking? Can you maybe provide links to the products or provide part numbers?

Comment: Welcome! Would you mind to provide some details, like links to data sheets of the LED stripes, and a (simplified) schematic? Or if this is a software problem, show us some code? -- Since you're apparently have been here some time already, you know for sure that you can [edit] your question, don't you?

Comment: use a level shifter

Comment: Thanks busybee for helping me to make my project at the moment I have little knowledge about 5v strip it’s sk6812 5050 individually addressable but soon I can send you all the information with data sheet because 12v strips still not in my hand but thanks so much helping me I promise as soon as I got the shippment I’ll provide all the details ok dear I’ll get back to you asa I get me strips